# Choosing theme on the fly and passing parameters

Tags: php, wordpress

My designer gave me four different templates, one for

```
mobile-index-page
mobile-searchresult-page
desktop-index-page
desktop-searchresult-page
```

I learnt how to switch the theme if mobile or not already, but how do I pass parameters(via GET) and choose the searchresult theme with them?

Answer (score 0):

To pass parameters,encode them in the URL and read them through $_GET, simply add parameters to the url

```
http://www.example.com/page.php?mobile=false
```

On the page you may check for the mobile value through `$_GET` and conclude

```
if(isset($_GET['mobile']) && mobile==false){
//it's not mobile
}else{
//it's mobile
}
```

Comment: Okay, how do I choose a certain template based on $_GET?